# How do I insert a page break after every table in a document?

Tags: vba, ms-word

new VBA user here. I have an MS Word document with 30 tables that I created outside of Office. I would like to insert a page break after every table in the document. I tried this VBA macro to insert the break at every paragraph as a placeholder for the table:

```
Sub InsertBreak()
Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(2).Range
With myRange
 .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
 .InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
End With
End Sub
```

This just adds one page break before the first table in the doc. I would like to insert page breaks at every table (paragraph) starting from the second not the first. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub InsertPgBreak()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To ActiveDocument.Tables.Count
        ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Range.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
    Next i
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Selection.InsertBreak method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.insertbreak?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm158662778)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)