# Insert page break after every table and keep caption with table?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I posted about [How do I insert a page break after every table in a document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77688315/how-do-i-insert-a-page-break-after-every-table-in-a-document). Now I have captions above all my tables (Style = Table Caption). When I run the macro from user taller, each caption remains on the page before the break. I would like the captions to stay with the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `Find` method to locate all table caption, then insert a page break

```vb
Sub InsertPageBreakAtCaptionEnd()
    Dim docRng As Range
'    Const STYLE_NAME = "Caption"  ' for testing
    Const STYLE_NAME = "Table Caption"  ' modify as needed
    Set docRng = ActiveDocument.Content
    With docRng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(STYLE_NAME)
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        Do While .Execute
            docRng.Collapse Word.wdCollapseStart
            docRng.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
            docRng.Move Word.wdParagraph, 1
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: From reading the question I believe the caption comes before the table, so the break would need to be at the start of the caption.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry I did not make that clear and I have edited the question.

Comment: I've update the code. @TimothyRylatt always correctly catches the details.

Comment: Thanks this answers my question but also inserts a page break at the top of page 1. So page 1 is blank and the first caption and table appear on page 2. It would be nice if the first caption and table appeared on page 1 instead.

Comment: It's doable. I've update the answer.